# How to put console command from a frontend button?

Tags: php, symfony, controller

I am a newbie in Symfony. Anyhow I have found my way to build up a Console Command. So this command needs to be accessible from the frontend.

So by my opinion, I need to put the command to service. I have followed this [link](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/console/commands_as_services.html).
So this should be created. But now I don't know how to connect this service to the actual route call. 
I have formed a route like this:

```
command:
    path:               /command
    defaults:
        _controller:    AppBundle:Command:activate
    requirements:
        language:       '%pimc.akeneo_cms.frontend.language.available%'
```

And I have created new controller called CommandController with just one method called activateAction(). 
And I don't know what to put in actiavateAction ?

Could someone help me ? Am I on a right path ?

Comment: That's a strange way to do it.

Your command car call a service via dependency injection, the same service that your controller action call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow these steps:

- create the console command
- create the controller with an action method and a route
- create a twig template to be rendered from the controller's method action
- inside the template, create a button
- using ajax, on button click, make a request into that controller's method action (or another method action)
- inside the method, call the console command as [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/command_in_controller.html) is explained

Comment: Well, it doesn't work. But this is happening because of my command, which needs around 30 minutes in order to accomplish. But from your logic perspective, everything works swell.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run a command in your controller's action, you can use `Application`:

```
$application = new Application($this->get('kernel'));
$input = new ArrayInput(array('command' => 'your:command'));
$output = new BufferedOutput();
$application->run($input, $output);
```

And if you want to check the output of the command you can use `$output->fetch()`.

Comment: Thank you too for taking the time to answer to me.